# Fetching a batch of documents in firebase database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I'm migrating one couch db to firebase database. lets suppose I have data like in firebase database, I want to fetch data based on startKey and endKey like in couch DB.

`all_docs?include_docs=true&startkey="test_1"&endkey="test_3"`

I am using firebase admin sdk and nodejs.
How I can achieve that in firebase database?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for querying Realtime Database with the admin SDK?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries

Answer (score 2):

It is almost the same in firebase.

Direct yourself to that position in the database using 'ref' function and then use

```
var ref = db.ref("users\user1");
ref.orderByKey().startAt("test_1").endAt("test_3").once("value", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

As mentioned in the comments the firebase documentation will help you a lot more.